# primeng: p-listbox with ng-template

Tags: primeng

I'm running this project in stackblitz:
[p-listbox project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9ykes)

It works fine.
But I have to work with an older version of primeng: 8.0.2
Is it possible that ng-template is not supported in this version ?

Is it possible to create a stacblitz anguar project with a specified version of angualr, primeng ?

Thank you,

Zvika

Comment: You can edit the `package.json` file and enter the versions you want for the different packages.

Comment: Thank you very much !  Is it possible to know to what primeng version should I upgrade ?  I tried primeng 10.0.0 but then I got errors in primeng code. Probably because I'm using cli 8.3.8 .

Answer (score 1):

ng-template is part of angular. not primeng.
Following is a sample HTML code.

```html
<p-listbox [style]="{'width':'15rem'}" [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name" [checkbox]="true" > 
        <ng-template let-city pTemplate="item">
            <div class="p-grid p-align-center p-nogutter">
                <div class="col1">{{city.value.name}}</div> 
                <div class="col2">{{city.value.code}}</div> 
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-listbox>
```

In this case primeng upgrage is not required.

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `package.json` file and enter the versions you want for the different packages.

Regarding matching PrimeNG and Angular versions, according to their [site](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v12-0-0-is-here/), you should always match the major version of PrimeNG to that of the major version of Angular you're using.
If you're using PrimNG 10.0.0 (maybe it's better to take the latest minor version, 10.0.3, which probably includes various bug fixes), you should use Angular 10.